# How to store multiple username and password in localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, authentication, local-storage

```
function store(){

var name = document.getElementById('ruserName');
var pw = document.getElementById('rpassword');
var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
var numbers = /[0-9]/g;

if(ruserName.value.length == 0 && rpassword.value.length != 0){
    alert('Please fill in Username');


}else if(rpassword.value.length == 0 && ruserName.value.length != 0){
    alert('Please fill in password');

}else if(ruserName.value.length == 0 && rpassword.value.length == 0){
    alert('Please fill in Username and password');

}else if(rpassword.value.length < 8){
    alert('Min of 8 characters for password');

}else if(!rpassword.value.match(numbers)){
    alert('please add 1 number');

}else if(!rpassword.value.match(upperCaseLetters)){
    alert('please add 1 uppercase letter');

}else if(!rpassword.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)){
    alert('please add 1 lovercase letter');

}else{
    localStorage.setItem('ruserName', ruserName.value);
    localStorage.setItem('rpassword', rpassword.value);
    alert('Your account has been created with Username ' + ruserName.value + "." + " Welcome to Zack's Tech Shop " + ruserName.value + "!");
}
```

}

```
function check(){
var storedName = localStorage.getItem('ruserName');
var storedPw = localStorage.getItem('rpassword');

var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
var userPw = document.getElementById('password');


if(userName.value == storedName && password.value == storedPw){
    alert('You are logged in. Welcome back ' + userName.value);
}else{
    alert('Error on login');
}
```

}

My registration form only can store data of 1 user and when I try to sign up for a new account it replaces the account that I created before. How do I make it so that the user can make multiple accounts? The first function is for my registration and the second one is for the login. This is for my assignment

Comment: use an array in localStorage, with JSON.stringify to store and JSON.parse to read

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you don't store sensitive data in localStorage.

Please read about [localStorage](https://snyk.io/blog/is-localstorage-safe-to-use/) before you continue with this approach.

Comment: I get it but this is just for an assignment no one is actually going to input their passwords